# Removing all digits from a string on python

Tags: python, regex

So i need some help on removing the digits from this string

`import re`

`g="C0N4rtist"`

`re.sub(r'\W','',g)'`

`print(re.sub(r'\W','',g))`

it should look like

`CNrtist`

but instead it gives me
 `04`

I've made this code from researching online, and i've used this site http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html for help. In my eyes, the code should work, and i have no clue what's wrong, so letting me know what's wrong would be very helpful as I've already researched online and in stackoverflow.

Comment: Or just use a generator expression instead of `re`: `print(''.join(x for x in g if not x in "0123456789"))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\d` for digits:

```
>>> import re
>>> g = "C0N4rtist"
>>> re.sub(r'\d+', '', g)
'CNrtist'
```

Note that you don't need regex for this, `str.translate` is very fast compared to the regex version

```
>>> from string import digits
>>> g.translate(None, digits)
'CNrtist'
```

**Timings:**

```
>>> g = "C0N4rtist"*100
>>> %timeit g.translate(None, digits)      #winner
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.98 us per loop
>>> %timeit ''.join(i for i in g if not i.isdigit())
1000 loops, best of 3: 507 us per loop
>>> %timeit re.sub(r'\d+', '', g)
1000 loops, best of 3: 253 us per loop
>>> %timeit ''.join([i for i in g if not i.isdigit()])
1000 loops, best of 3: 352 us per loop
>>> %timeit ''.join([i for i in g if i not in digits])
1000 loops, best of 3: 277 us per loop
```

Comment: The translate takes a slightly different form for Python 3.x though: `g.translate(dict.fromkeys(map(ord, '0123456789')))` (you may also want to just try `\d` for the regex version, as the regex engine doesn't need to worry about run lengths or anything, so it might be introducing some unnecessary overhead)

Comment: +1 for `translate`, but IMO it should only be used in performance-critical situations as I think a generator expression is a bit more readable.

Comment: Well, it's not a completely fair timing as the generator expression can obviously be optimized using `in` and a set of the digits, but I think translate will still be faster than that :)

Comment: @l4mpi In fact generator expression is always slower with `str.join`, as it requires double iteration.

Comment: Yes, but `isdigit` has a performance overhead as well, as shown by your new timings. Interesting to see that the list comprehension is considerably faster than the generator expression, I didn't think it would make that much of a difference... but of course iterating over a generator will be slower than iterating over a list.

Comment: @l4mpi Actually `str.join` is a [special case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/846892).

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use regex for this. you can use isdigit() function

```
   def removeDigitsFromStr(_str):
        result = ''.join(i for i in _str if not i.isdigit())
        return result
```

Comment: I would prefer to use `in` in this case, as in `... if not i in digits`, where `digits` is `"0123456789"` or `set("0123456789")` - but that's mainly personal preference in this case and does not make much of a difference unless the code is performance-critical.

Comment: I agree. Thanks for bringing this up