# How to remove digits from the end of a string in Python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, split

I want to remove digits from the end of a string, but I have no idea.

Can the `split()` method work? How can I make that work?

The initial string looks like `asdfg123`,and I only want `asdfg` instead.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing all digits from a string on python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335679/removing-all-digits-from-a-string-on-python)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

No, split would not work, because split only can work with a fixed string to split on.

You could use the [`str.rstrip()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip):

```
import string

cleaned = yourstring.rstrip(string.digits)
```

This uses the [`string.digits` constant](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.digits) as a convenient definition of what needs to be removed.

or you could use a regular expression to replace digits at the end with an empty string:

```
import re

cleaned = re.sub(r'\d+$', '', yourstring)
```

Comment: Thanks!!That really helps!

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`str.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) with digit characters you want to remove trailing characters of the string:

```
>>> 'asdfg123'.rstrip('0123456789')
'asdfg'
```

Alternatively, you can use [`string.digits`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.digits) instead of `'0123456789'`:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.digits
'0123456789'
>>> 'asdfg123'.rstrip(string.digits)
'asdfg'
```

Comment: Thanks!!That really helps!

Answer (score 0):

Regex!

```
import re
intialString = "asdfg123"
newString = re.search("[^\d]*", intialString).group()
print(newString)
```

Expected Outcome is "asdfg".